# How to change register link in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to change my register link to  domain.com/register?ref=abc
how to do it in laravel 5.5?

```
<a style="margin-bottom: 5px;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 600;" href="{{ route('login') }}" class=""><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log In</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="margin-bottom: 5px;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 600;" href="{{ route('register') }}" class=""><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Registration</a>
```

Comment: change the route name from `routes/web.php`

Comment: it is not present in web routes

Comment: then how on earth you expect to visit the route? I think you have problem with your html form. Edit and post the form please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Overrating the default `auth`routes :

You can overrite the default auth routes by putting on your `routes/web.php` and changing them to your needs :

```
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

### 2. Changing it directly on the html anchor tag :

You can omit the `named routes` and use a direct link :

```
<a style="margin-bottom: 5px;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 600;" href="http://example.com/register?ref=abc" class=""><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Registration</a>
```

#### OR

```
<a style="margin-bottom: 5px;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 600;" href="{{ route('register') }}/?ref=abc" class=""><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Registration</a>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: please can you tell where will be route for it it is not preset in routes/ web